Issue with using realloc - not getting expected amount of memory
I have to write a program that is able to take in a file of grades, read them, and then provide some options to be able to edit that file. I decided to write it in C (for the challenge, and to learn more about C). I have a function that receives a pointer, and then opens a file and loads the characters from that file, into the memory provided by that pointer.
The issue I am having is while using realloc to get a list size big enough to load the file in. I'm currently just loading in a filler size.
For reference:
Function to load in data from file to list.
void loadFile(char **fileContents) {
  printf("%p\n", *fileContents);
  *fileContents = realloc(*fileContents, 200);
  printf("%p\n", *fileContents);
  printf("%zu\n", sizeof *fileContents);
}

Function to select various options to edit that list (also where fileContents is declared).
void menu() {
  char *fileContents = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);
  if (fileContents == NULL) {
    puts("memory failed to initialize");
  }

  loadFile(&fileContents);

  printf("%s\n", fileContents);

  free(fileContents);
}

I was expecting to get a size of 200 for the last print statement in the loadFile function, but instead I got 4.

To summarize: The size of a pointer is the size of the pointer itself, not what it might point to.

Note that the correct printf() conversion specifier for sizeof, or size_t values in general, is %zu and not %d.

In your loadFile function, fileContents is a pointer. Evidently on your system, pointers are 32-bits or 4 bytes.
The pointer you get back from malloc, calloc, realloc doesn't carry any information about how much data was allocated. It's just a pointer to the beginning of that memory block.
As a further note, there is no guarantee these functions succeed. You should test to ensure they do. If they fail you can either print an error and exit or try to recover.
However, in order to do this with realloc you want to first assign the result to a temporary variable. If it failed in your case, the memory pointed to by *fileContents would no longer have a pointer pointing to it. This can cause a memory leak, since we could no longer free it.

Ahhh ok that makes sense. Thanks a lot! I was thinking that I would be able to access the amount of memory I got back from realloc. Turns out 4 was the proper output, just not the one I expected :)

Get used to that feeling. "It's always your fault"

Lol the full story started off as that- I guess I'm going full circle.

@fwamingo273 "I was thinking that I would be able to access the amount of memory I got back from realloc" --> Curious, if that was true, then we would have a new problem: how to find the size of the pointer.

@Chris Except when C programming in 2024 using the latest version of the mainstream compilers. Then it is quite likely the compiler's fault. I encounter compiler bugs on weekly basis these days. Back in 2008 when that blog was written, I encountered one compiler bug per year at most.

@Lundin the price for living on the edge? I think there's a healthy middle ground between the latest versions of clang/gcc and Turbo C where that post is still true.

Yeah that middle ground is roughly gcc version 7 or whatever, which is well over 10 years old. It is troubling that it never settles and no new stable version is ever released, maybe the beginning of the end of open source compilers.
